# Espresso. intent matcher not matching

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

I have this code to match an `Intent`:

```kotlin
intended(allOf(
    hasAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW),
    hasData(Uri.parse("http://www.ya.ru/")),
    toPackage("com.android.chrome"),
))
```

but my test fails with this log output:

```
IntentMatcher: (has action: is "android.intent.action.VIEW" and has data: is http://www.ya.ru/ and resolvesTo: com.android.chrome)


Matched intents:[]

Recorded intents:
-Intent { dat=file:///... flg=0x10008000 cmp=com.ncloudtech.cloudoffice/.android.myword.TextEditorActivity_ (has extras) } handling packages:[[MY_APP_PACKAGE_HERE]], extras:[Bundle[{noDuplicateToRecentWithCopy=false, notSavedLocally=true, fileName=New Document.xodt, fileSize=0, isNewLocal=true, fileEditOnlineFileId=null, fileMediaType=application/vnd.collabio.xodocuments.document, FileStorage=-3, openDocumentType=1}]])
-Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.ya.ru/... } handling packages:[[com.android.chrome]])
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
```

What am I doing wrong?

The problem is due to the `hasData` `Matcher`:

```kotlin
hasData(Uri.parse("http://www.ya.ru/")),
```

When I remove it the test passes, but I want to check that the correct URL is transmitted to the browser.

Comment: I'm assuming that the matcher `hasData()` is trying to match the URI exactly. However, the URI you are testing against probably starts with `http://www.ya.ru/` but has additional path parameters in it. You'll need to find a different way to match just the parts of the URI instead of the entire thing.

Comment: @DavidWasser Do you know how to get the logs to include the full URL?

Comment: @JustTheHighlights sorry, no.

Comment: Found a way. You can use `Intents.getIntents()` and then log the intent data.